# Define local property for list of bean refs in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring 3.x

I have a growing list of filters in a `filter-chain` and am looking for a way to reduce the verbosity of these declarations in my context file. eg, using the example from the [spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
  <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/webServices/**" filters="
       securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCFalse,
       basicAuthenticationFilter,
       exceptionTranslationFilter,
       filterSecurityInterceptor" />
  </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Imagine we have many patterns that all require the same filter chain, I want to be able to define a string local to this context like `"
           securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCFalse,
           basicAuthenticationFilter,
           exceptionTranslationFilter,
           filterSecurityInterceptor"` and use it in the context like so

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
  <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/foo/**" filters="${defaultFilterChain}" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/bar/**" filters="${defaultFilterChain}" />
    ...
  </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

Properties are not of use here, as they will be treated as a String, not as a list that can be used as bean refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?87497-PropertyOverrideConfigurer-for-bean-references

Answer (score 0):

Replacing property placeholders like that is done using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which can take properties from external resources, but it can also take properties directly and it can use both external and directly configured at the same time. External properties will override directly configured properties, making directly configured properties useful as defaults (this behavior can be switched off making it the other way around).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="properties">
    <props>
      <prop key="defaultFilterChain">securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCFalse, basicAuthenticationFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, filterSecurityInterceptor</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Been down this road, this is actually treated as a String, not as a list of bean refs. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114074-Defining-a-string-property-for-use-within-the-local-context&p=378096#post378096

Comment: ah, now i see the problem, then you can use `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean` or `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean` to configure a map/properties instance with references to your filters